# Split strings of multi columns to multi columns and rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, split

I have a table like this:

| Id | oldduedatehistory | extenddatehistory | newduedatehistory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-02,2022-02-02,2022-03-02 | 2022-01-01,2022-01-30,2022-03-02 | 2022-02-02,2022-03-02,202-04-05 |

Now I want to split string value of these columns and get a table like this:

| Id | oldduedatehistory | extenddatehistory | newduedatehistory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-02 |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-01-30 | 2022-03-02 |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 | 2022-03-02 | 2022-04-05 |

Using `string _split`, I just can split one column, but I want to split these 3 columns in one query, and consider that I want all the columns split in a way that first string of these columns put in columns of one row, second string in another row, third string in another row (as you see in the desired table)

---

Well I find a way that i can solve my problem:

```
With x as (
Select Id,x.value, row_number() over (partition by id order by x.value) as xRowNum
From Table t
Cross Apply string_split(oldduedatehistory,',','') x )
,y as (
Select Id,y.value, row_number() over (partition by id order by y.value) as yRowNum
From Table t
Cross Apply string_split(extenddatehistory,',','') y )
,z as (
Select Id,z.value, row_number() over (partition by id order by z.value) as zRowNum
From Table t
Cross Apply string_split(extenddatehistory,',','') z)
select x.loanid,x.value,y.value,z.value
from x
join y on x.id=y.id and x.xRowNum=y.yRowNum
join z on z.id=z.id and y.yRowNum=z.zRowNum
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: you can use STRING_SPLIT together with enable_ordinal = 1 parameter, it will return 1,2,3 for every splitted row. then you just join them together

Comment: I *really* hope the reason you are asking this question is to fix your design. If it isn't, it should be.

Comment: Create a tally from 1 till number of commas(,) in a column and substring() each column repeatedly: `select id, substring(oldduedatehistory, n.n+(n.n-1)*10, 10), substring(extenddatehistory, n.n+(n.n-1)*10, 10),   substring(newduedatehistory, n.n+(n.n-1)*10, 10) from tableX as t cross apply (   select top(1+len(t.oldduedatehistory)-len(replace(t.oldduedatehistory,',',''))) row_number() over(order by @@spid) as n   from sys.all_objects as a with(nolock)) as n`

Comment: @lptr Thank you but it does not work for this problem

Comment: @ThomA That is not my design and of course I want to fix it that I am asking this question.

Comment: If you are on sql server 2016 and newer, you could use openjson: `select t.id, o.value, e.value, n.value
from tableX as t
cross apply openjson('["'+replace(string_escape(oldduedatehistory, 'json'), ',', '","')+'"]') as o
cross apply openjson('["'+replace(string_escape(extenddatehistory, 'json'), ',', '","')+'"]') as e
cross apply openjson('["'+replace(string_escape(newduedatehistory, 'json'), ',', '","')+'"]') as n
where o.[key]=e.[key] and o.[key]=n.[key]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
select id, x.value, y.value, z.value
from (
    VALUES  (N'1', N'2022-01-02,2022-02-02,2022-03-02', N'2022-01-01,2022-01-30,2022-03-02', N'2022-02-02,2022-03-02,2022-04-05')
) t (Id,oldduedatehistory,extenddatehistory,newduedatehistory)
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.oldduedatehistory, ',', 1) x
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.extenddatehistory, ',', 1) y
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.newduedatehistory, ',', 1) z
where x.ordinal = y.ordinal
and y.ordinal = z.ordinal
```

This needs SQL Server 2022 though.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/SvcQXhnC

Comment: Thank You, It does not work on my SQL Server version, but it gave me an idea to solve the problem